# Potplayer blocked from accessing graphics hardware - why?

Tags: windows-10, daum-pot-player

Why is potplayer blocked from accessing graphics hardware?

[image: application potplayer mini has been blocked from accessing graphics hardware]

Answer (score 0):

Try to update/re-install graphics driver and check the result.

You can update the driver via Windows Update:
Device Manager – Display adapters – right click your display and select Update Driver Software – follow up the wizard to complete the update.

Or, you can access graphic hardware official website, manually search/download appropriate driver via hardware model, then, re-install it on your system.

**How to: Install and Update Hardware Drivers in Windows 10**:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/how-to-install-and-update-hardware-drivers-in/a97bbbd1-9973-4d66-9a5b-291300006293